# ls and vim color on SunOS 5.8/Solaris 8

Tags: vim, ls, colors, solaris

I want to use `ls` and `vim` with color on SunOS 5.8:

```
SunOS 5.8 Generic_117350-11 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Blade-2500
```

I have installed ls (GNU coreutils) 6.9 and vim 7.2

#### In ~/.cshrc:

```
setenv TERM sun-color # If change to dtterm, the vim color scheme desert256 will not work.

alias ls ls -F --color=auto

setenv LS_COLORS "no=00;38;5;244:di=00;38;5;33:ln=01;38;5;37:pi=48;5;230;38;5;136;01:so=48;5;230;38;5;136;01:do=48;5;230;38;5;136;01:bd=48;5;230;38;5;244;01:cd=48;5;230;38;5;244;01:or=48;5;235;38;5;160:ex=01;38;5;64:*.tar=00;38;5;61:*.tgz=01;38;5;61:*.arj=01;38;5;61:*.taz=01;38;5;61:*.lzh=01;38;5;61:*.lzma=01;38;5;61:*.tlz=01;38;5;61:*.txz=01;38;5;61:*.zip=01;38;5;61:*.z=01;38;5;61:*.Z=01;38;5;61:*.dz=01;38;5;61:*.gz=01;38;5;61:*.lz=01;38;5;61:*.xz=01;38;5;61:*.bz2=01;38;5;61:*.bz=01;38;5;61:*.tbz=01;38;5;61:*.tbz2=01;38;5;61:*.tz=01;38;5;61:*.deb=01;38;5;61:*.rpm=01;38;5;61:*.jar=01;38;5;61:*.rar=01;38;5;61:*.ace=01;38;5;61:*.zoo=01;38;5;61:*.cpio=01;38;5;61:*.7z=01;38;5;61:*.rz=01;38;5;61:*.apk=01;38;5;61:*.gem=01;38;5;61:*.jpg=00;38;5;136:*.JPG=00;38;5;136:*.jpeg=00;38;5;136:*.gif=00;38;5;136:*.bmp=00;38;5;136:*.pbm=00;38;5;136:*.pgm=00;38;5;136:*.ppm=00;38;5;136:*.tga=00;38;5;136:*.xbm=00;38;5;136:*.xpm=00;38;5;136:*.tif=00;38;5;136:*.tiff=00;38;5;136:*.png=00;38;5;136:*.svg=00;38;5;136:*.svgz=00;38;5;136:*.mng=00;38;5;136:*.pcx=00;38;5;136:*.dl=00;38;5;136:*.xcf=00;38;5;136:*.xwd=00;38;5;136:*.yuv=00;38;5;136:*.cgm=00;38;5;136:*.emf=00;38;5;136:*.eps=00;38;5;136:*.CR2=00;38;5;136:*.ico=00;38;5;136:*.tex=01;38;5;245:*.rdf=01;38;5;245:*.owl=01;38;5;245:*.n3=01;38;5;245:*.ttl=01;38;5;245:*.nt=01;38;5;245:*.torrent=01;38;5;245:*.xml=01;38;5;245:*Makefile=01;38;5;245:*Rakefile=01;38;5;245:*build.xml=01;38;5;245:*rc=01;38;5;245:*1=01;38;5;245:*.nfo=01;38;5;245:*README=01;38;5;245:*README.txt=01;38;5;245:*readme.txt=01;38;5;245:*.md=01;38;5;245:*README.markdown=01;38;5;245:*.ini=01;38;5;245:*.yml=01;38;5;245:*.cfg=01;38;5;245:*.conf=01;38;5;245:*.c=01;38;5;245:*.cpp=01;38;5;245:*.cc=01;38;5;245:*.log=00;38;5;240:*.bak=00;38;5;240:*.aux=00;38;5;240:*.bbl=00;38;5;240:*.blg=00;38;5;240:*~=00;38;5;240:*#=00;38;5;240:*.part=00;38;5;240:*.incomplete=00;38;5;240:*.swp=00;38;5;240:*.tmp=00;38;5;240:*.temp=00;38;5;240:*.o=00;38;5;240:*.pyc=00;38;5;240:*.class=00;38;5;240:*.cache=00;38;5;240:*.aac=00;38;5;166:*.au=00;38;5;166:*.flac=00;38;5;166:*.mid=00;38;5;166:*.midi=00;38;5;166:*.mka=00;38;5;166:*.mp3=00;38;5;166:*.mpc=00;38;5;166:*.ogg=00;38;5;166:*.ra=00;38;5;166:*.wav=00;38;5;166:*.m4a=00;38;5;166:*.axa=00;38;5;166:*.oga=00;38;5;166:*.spx=00;38;5;166:*.xspf=00;38;5;166:*.mov=01;38;5;166:*.mpg=01;38;5;166:*.mpeg=01;38;5;166:*.m2v=01;38;5;166:*.mkv=01;38;5;166:*.ogm=01;38;5;166:*.mp4=01;38;5;166:*.m4v=01;38;5;166:*.mp4v=01;38;5;166:*.vob=01;38;5;166:*.qt=01;38;5;166:*.nuv=01;38;5;166:*.wmv=01;38;5;166:*.asf=01;38;5;166:*.rm=01;38;5;166:*.rmvb=01;38;5;166:*.flc=01;38;5;166:*.avi=01;38;5;166:*.fli=01;38;5;166:*.flv=01;38;5;166:*.gl=01;38;5;166:*.m2ts=01;38;5;166:*.divx=01;38;5;166:*.webm=01;38;5;166:*.axv=01;38;5;166:*.anx=01;38;5;166:*.ogv=01;38;5;166:*.ogx=01;38;5;166:"
```

I tried to put it into `~/.dircolors` or `~/.dir_colors`, but it doesn't work, and I cannot find out the dircolors command.

#### in `~/.vimrc`:

```
 set t_Co=256
 set background=dark
 colorscheme desert256
```

The `tput colors` output:

```
$ tput colors
8
$ echo $?
0
```

After the above settings, after I used the latest version of PuTTY to log in the SunOS host, PuTTY is still under default setting.

`ls` and `vim` can show with color in PuTTY.

However, if I do `su - myaccount` from a Common Desk Environment (CDE) Terminal Emulator in the SunOS computer, then `ls` and `vim` (gvim, however, *can* show with color) cannot work correctly with color as PuTTY, no matter whether the Terminal Emulator is `background:Black`, `forceground:White` or `background:White`, `forceground:Black`.

Please see the pics: https://picasaweb.google.com/112839698018484354718/Sunos58

How can I let `ls` and `vim` show with color correctly in SunOS CDE Terminal Emulator like that when I log into that SunOS host from PuTTY?

Comment: in order to enable synatx highlighting in vim, be sure to put `syntax on` in your `$HOME/.vimrc` file.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're refferring to [DtTerm](http://cdesktopenv.sourceforge.net/man1/dtterm.html). In this case, you're only limited to 16 colors: despite having a nice GUI, `DtTerm` is inferior feature-wise compared to `xterm`, `rxvt` and others.

If you want 256 color support in your terminal, pick a [recent xterm build](http://www.opencsw.org/packages/CSWxterm/) (*not* the one shipped with Solaris).

Another option is using `gvim` with a Motif/Athena/GTK GUI.

Comment: The xterm shipped with Solaris 11 is recent enough, but then Solaris 11 shipped 12 years after Solaris 8 did - nothing from Solaris 8 is recent now.